# Why doesn't Android's shadowRadius work with a 0 value in XML?

Tags: android, xml, android-styles

In an Android app that's targeting Marshmallow, I want to apply a non-blurry shadow to the text of a button. With a shadowRadius of 1 or higher, I see the shadow:

[image: one]

But if I try to make the shadowRadius anything between 0 and 0.99, nothing shows up:

[image: less than one]

I'm just trying to achieve a no-blur shadow like you can do with the `text-shadow` property in CSS:

[image: css]

Here is the associated XML that I have set up for my button style.

```
    <style name="ButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    .
    .
    .
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">2</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">7</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">0.99</item>
    .
    .
    .
</style>
```

The only thing I could think of that was unique to my style was that I set `stateListAnimator` to null, but even without that I have this problem. I see a lot of example code online mentioning that you can make the shadowRadius something small like 0.01 but I'm not seeing any shadow once I make it smaller than 1. Did something change in the Android platform recently?